# How do I transpose the pitch of a .wav in .net C#

Tags: c#, naudio, cscore

I'm trying to create a small utility application (console app or winforms) in C# that will load a single cycle waveform. The user can then enter a chord, and the app will generate a "single cycle chord", ie: a perfectly loopable version of the chord.
A perfect fifth (is not a chord but 2 notes) for instance would be the original single cycle looped twice, mixed with a second copy of the single cycle, transposed 7 semitones up and looped 3 times in the same timeframe.

What I can't find is how to transpose the wave simply by playing it faster, just like most basic samplers do. What would be a good way to do this in C#?

I've tried NAudio and cscore, but can't find how to play the wave at a different pitch by playing it faster. The pitch shift and varispeed examples are not the thing I'm looking for because those either try to keep the length the same or try to keep the pitch the same.

Comment: It is not that simple.  If you want to keep the shifted notes to have the same duration.  http://www.guitarpitchshifter.com/algorithm.html

Comment: It's not clear where you'e going with 'play it faster' because you're also talking about mixing it, which implies you are mixing it in the digital domain and then playing back the resulting combined waveform.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I don't want the shifted notes to have the same duration. I'm talking about single cycle waveforms, which - when looped - basically behave like an oscillator, meaning higher notes should result in shorter waves. In other words, I just want to play it faster and higher without any compensation for time or pitch.

Comment: @peterG Yes the mixing part worked with the help of NAudio, layering the same wav transposed is what the challenge is now. By play faster, I mean increase pitch and shorten duration.